# HQL: Using Boolean in Named Queries

Tags: hibernate, hql, boolean, named

Can you please help me? I have error in querying boolean value "r.isDefault = true".

In my HQL named query:

```
<named-query name="RptQuery.queryDefaultByCode">
    <query>
        SELECT r FROM RptQuery r WHERE r.code = ?1 AND r.isDefault = true
    </query>
</named-query>
```

I get error:
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: RptQuery.queryDefaultByCode

In my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions" value="true='Y', false='N', yes='Y', no='N'"/>
```

In my pojo:

```
private boolean isDefault;

@Column(name = "CPMN_IS_DEFLT", length = 1)
@Type(type = "yes_no")
public boolean isDefault() {
    return this.isDefault;
}

public void setDefault(boolean isDefault) {
    this.isDefault = isDefault;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer:
Just found a minor error:

```
r.isDefault = true
```

should be

```
r.default = true
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and it works, please post your solution as answer and accept your own answer. It will help others

Comment: Why it is r.default and not r.isDefault?

Answer (score 48):

try this : `where r.isDefault is true`